# Cannot access Childen of JSON

Tags: json, json.net, jsonserializer

I need to be able to loop through each "item" from my JSON result. The JSON response looks like this. I would like to be able to access each specific id.

```
{
"prop1": {
"date": "2017-03-04 3:57:38 PM",
"item": [
  {
    "id": "37705",
    "date": "2016-04-03",
    "time": "1:30PM"
    },
    "location": "Location 1"
  },
{
    "id": "2000",
    "date": "2016-05-03",
    "time": "2:30PM"
    },
    "location": "Location 2"
  },
  ] 
 }
}
```

This is what i have but i am getting "Cannot access Children"

```
using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stream))
                    {
                        dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);

                        foreach (var item in obj)
                        {
                            foreach (var item2 in item["item"].Children())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(item2.id);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Half of these objects don't have children.

Comment: Your JSON as shown is not valid.  Try validating it at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jsonlint.com/.